# Setting all the Chart attributes in a report (rdlc) through code in report viewer

Tags: reportviewer

I've created a RDLC file to view report and i've a line chart in it. I want to set the properties of the chart such as category, X axis interval, Y axis interval, colors etc dynamically. How can i set them through code? I'm using C#.Net.

Thank you
NLV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping there is a better way, but as you posted this a while ago I'm guessing there is not.  The only thing I can think of is that since the .rdlc file is actually just XML, you open it in the C# and change the attributes to what you want depending on the data you have.